# java eclipse how to generate java classes from wsdl

Tags: java, class, wsdl

I work with Eclipse and I have a wsdl. Now, I need to generate the java classes from this wsdl.

How can I do this from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to familiar with `maven`, add following dependencies and some configuration for your `WSDL` files.

1) First add these **Dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2) Add Configuration for `WSDL` file

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wsimport-from-jdk</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>
                        https://example.com/mywsdl.wsdl
                    </wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
                <packageName>com.sample.wsdl.client</packageName>
                <sourceDestDir>src\main\java</sourceDestDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

3) Build source code

> `mvn generate-sources` run this command in your root folder of this project where `pom.xml`resides.

For more details [github sample](https://github.com/hafizusman530/wsdl-to-pojo)

Comment: What's the equivalent of <configuration> <wsdlUrls> <wsdlUrl/> for a local file? Or should I give it the (relative) file path as a URL?

Comment: The equivalent is `<wsdlFiles><wsdlFile/>`

Comment: Use newer versions of the JAX-WS libraries (2.3.1) and of the plugin (2.6) to work with Java 11 or later